# How to correct use Zend 2 alpha filter?

Tags: filter, zend-framework2

I need do filter client names with [Zend Filters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.filter.set.html).

But it simply don't working. How can I correct this?

**Code:**

```
<?php
$nameFilter = new Zend\I18n\Filter\Alpha();
$nameFilter->setAllowWhiteSpace(true);
$nameFilter->setLocale('pt_BR');

var_dump($nameFilter->filter('Clíent Nãmeç'));
```

**Output:**
    null

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have php5 intl extension installed and loaded.

Maybe you should switch on error reporting in your app because this dependency is pretty displayed if you are using \Zend\I18n components.